# Power BI - DAX measure to reference a list of values. Calculate net turnover per broker - more elegant solution?

Tags: list, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

Below is a simplified version of transaction data for stocks.

```
StockData = 
DATATABLE (
    "STOCK", STRING,
    "Date", DATETIME,
    "Buyer", STRING,
    "Seller", STRING,
    "Turnover", INTEGER,
    {
         { "AAPL", "2019/04/07", "GSI", "BRC", 100 },
         { "AAPL", "2019/04/07", "CITI", "JPM", 500 },
         { "AAPL", "2019/04/07", "JPM", "GSI", 700 },
         { "AAPL", "2019/04/08", "GSI", "JPM", 300 },
         { "AAPL", "2019/04/08", "GSI", "CITI", 800 },
         { "AAPL", "2019/04/08", "JPM", "BRC", 400 },
         { "MSFT", "2019/04/07", "GSI", "GSI", 500 },
         { "MSFT", "2019/04/07", "JPM", "BRC", 700 },
         { "MSFT", "2019/04/07", "BRC", "GSI", 800 },
         { "MSFT", "2019/04/08", "GSI", "BRC", 500 },
         { "MSFT", "2019/04/08", "GSI", "JPM", 600 },
         { "MSFT", "2019/04/08", "CITI", "BRC", 500 }
    }
)
```

Goal is to calculate net turnover by broker per day.

I can achieve this by following DAX measure

```
Test BRC Net Turnover = 
VAR TotalBuy = CALCULATE(SUM(StockData[Turnover]),StockData[Buyer] = "BRC")
VAR TotalSell = CALCULATE(SUM(StockData[Turnover]),StockData[Seller] = "BRC")
Return TotalBuy - TotalSell
```

However, to get net turnover for all  (Four) brokers in example data above I have to rewrite the measure four times with different critera, i.e., rather than using "BRC" I have to use "GSI" etc...

Real data set consists of 50 different broker codes so the solution with 50 different measures is not feasible.

How can I make this DAX function iterate over all Broker codes in my data set. Taking into consideration filters for the stock. I.e., if a typical broker code doesnt exist for MSFT but for AAPL the measure will take that into consideration.

I have tried the `values` function to return a list of all brokers, without any success.[image]

Above is what I would like to achieve with one single measure.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplary well-written question!

---

To do this, let's first create an independent calculated table to use for the different buyers and sellers.

```
Brokers = VALUES( StockData[Buyer] )
```

Now we can put `Brokers[Buyer]` in the Legend field and write a measure that reads that value.

```
Net Turnover =
VAR Broker = SELECTEDVALUE ( Brokers[Buyer] )
VAR TotalBuy = CALCULATE ( SUM ( StockData[Turnover] ), StockData[Buyer] = Broker )
VAR TotalSell = CALCULATE ( SUM ( StockData[Turnover] ), StockData[Seller] = Broker )
RETURN
    TotalBuy - TotalSell
```

[image: Chart with Legend]

Comment: I'd probably do this as `AVERAGEX ( 'Brokers', [TotalBuy] - [TotalSell] )`, where [TotalBuy] and [TotalSell] are simple `SUM`s of the respective fields. This would give identical results whenever 'Brokers'[Buyer] is in the current context (like in your sample visual), but would give a per-buyer average at a total level. This would allow an easy way to compare buyers with something like `Buyer Turnover Difference from Average = [Net Turnover] / CALCULATE ( [Net Turnover], ALL ( 'Brokers' ) )`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @greggyb

where 
     "[TotalBuy] and [TotalSell] are simple SUMs of the respective fields."

The only field we can summarize in the sample above is the turnover field.

Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: Thank you Alexis solution works as intended.

Just one addition: Assume for one stock you only have GSI Selling. Then:

    `Brokers = VALUES( StockData[Buyer] )`

Would not include GSI. I solved this by using the following formula:

    `DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES(StockData[Buyer]),VALUES(StockData[Seller])))`

Comment: Apologies, Adni, I focused on the names of the measures you had written, rather than the schema of the table. I was thinking of buyer and seller being pivoted. That detail is less relevant than the structure of using `AVERAGEX`, which will give the totaling properties I discussed.